# Make UIImageView transparent and show UIImageView that is below it while touching

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, core-graphics

I have a requirement where I have a UIImageView on top of the other. I need to make the one on the top transparent while the user "draws" on it. Really instead of drawing what the user would be doing is "erasing" the top view letting the one below to be shown.

I been googling for a while and couldn't find a way of doing this. Where should I start reading?

My idea was subclassing `UIVIew` and in `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved` and `touchesEnded` handle the "erasing", but I have no idea how to erase!

Any clue so I can start reading documentation??

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You are using a no valid way to do what you want to do.
To draw (and erase) you should use the `CoreGraphics` and `Quartz2D` **Apple frameworks**.

[Here the Apple references to Quartz2D](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007533-SW1)

especially the [Path chapter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_paths/dq_paths.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH211-TPXREF101).

Answer (score 1):

i was going to suggest Core Animation as well https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html